# No value given for one or more required parameters (access)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have 2 datatable with these fields

***dataordner**

1. Archive Date/Time (datetimepicker, it's already data)
2. Storage Short Text (combobox)
3. BulanOrdner ShortText (combobox)
4. TahunOrdner Date/Time (datetimepicker)

***datalemari**

1. Archive Date/Time (datetimepicker, it's already data)
2. Storage Short Text (combobox)
3. Lemari Short Text (combobox)
4. BulanOrdner ShortText (combobox)
5. TahunOrdner Date/Time (datetimepicker)

and now I am very confused why i'm wrong

What I have tried:

I've done with my codes but always error with that error "no value given for one more...."

I call 2 table with if else in combobox(storage)

These are my code sequences, i think that's all true with selected item in combobox

**note:**

storage = combobox

```
Private Sub storage_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles storage.SelectedIndexChanged
If storage.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
    groupordner.Visible = True
    grouplemari.Visible = False
Else
    If storage.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        groupordner.Visible = False
        grouplemari.Visible = True
    End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles save.Click
If storage.SelectedItem = "Ordner" Then
    str = "Update dataordner set Storage = " & storage.Text & ", BulanOrdner = " & bulanordner.Text & ", TahunOrdner = '" & tahunordner.Value & "' Where Archive = '" & tanggalarchive.Value & "'"
    proses.ExecuteNonQuery(str)
    MsgBox("Data Has Been Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    Call bersih()
    Call data_penjualan()
Else
    If storage.SelectedItem = "Lemari" Then
        str = "Update datalemari set Storage = " & storage.Text & ", Lemari = " & lemari.Text & ", BulanLemari = " & bulanlemari.Text & ", TahunLemari = '" & tahunlemari.Value & "' Where Archive = '" & tanggalarchive.Value & "'"
        proses.ExecuteNonQuery(str)
        MsgBox("Data Has Been Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        Call bersih()
        Call data_penjualan()
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you actually look at the SQL code you're executing, rather than just the code that constructs it?  It really ought to be a no-brainer to look at the data that is causing an issue when data causes an issue.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i think my codes it's right, database and vb are very related to each other and there is no false, I'm only just confused why it don't want to enter

Comment: Did you look at it to make sure that it's right?  If not then what you think is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

There might me some control's value that is `null` or `Nothing`, you can use Debugging with Breakpoints to check null values Or there might be Objects that are not initialized.

You can also try the code below :

***Note*** : *I will recommend you to use Parameterized Query instead*

```
  Private Sub save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles save.Click
        If storage.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Plese Select the item first", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        Else

            If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
                conn.Open() '' Assuming conn is your OleDbConnection
            End If
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = conn.CreateCommand
            Try
                If storage.SelectedItem = "Ordner" Then
                     Str = "Update dataordner set Storage = " & storage.Text & ", BulanOrdner = " & bulanordner.Text & ", TahunOrdner = '" & tahunordner.Value & "' Where Archive = '" & tanggalarchive.Value & "'"
                    cmd.CommandText = Str
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MsgBox("Data Has Been Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                    Call bersih()
                    Call data_penjualan()
                Else
                    If storage.SelectedItem = "Lemari" Then
                        Str = "Update datalemari set Storage = " & storage.Text & ", Lemari = " & lemari.Text & ", BulanLemari = " & bulanlemari.Text & ", TahunLemari = '" & tahunlemari.Value & "' Where Archive = '" & tanggalarchive.Value & "'"
                        cmd.CommandText = Str
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        MsgBox("Data Has Been Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                        Call bersih()
                        Call data_penjualan()
                    End If
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Finally
                conn.Close()
            End Try

        End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: i've tried with that codes, but it's still not working, and still with same error :((